# How to get all friends' feed from Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use php sdk on my facebook app and ask for required extended permission.
I can get all statuses update from user who use my application from api call

```
$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses?limit=0');
```

But when I use the same method with this user's friend.

```
$friendStatuses = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/statuses?limit=0');
```

I got a blank array. I tried to not use "?limit=0" but the result is still the same.

I also tried to use

```
$friendFeed = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/feed?limit=0');
```

and got some feed from that user but not all. Even if I change "?limit=0" to "limit=1000" but the feed that I got is around 500 items but that user have more feed than that for sure.

My work is aim on collect user and friends' statuses and clustering them.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622096/facebook-graph-api-feeds-missing-in-json-response/

Answer (score 4):

The proper way to get a user's friend's feed is the last example you used:

```
$friendFeed = $facebook->api("/{$user_id}/feed?limit=0");
```

If you are getting some of the feed items, but not all of the ones you are expecting, it is possible you do not have the right permissions. The read_stream permission to see non-public posts, so, try double checking that you have the read_stream permission. You can check by running the FQL query:

```
SELECT read_stream FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()
```

I'm not 100% sure how you would do that with the SDK you are using, but it would probably be:

```
$readStream = $facebook->api("/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+read_stream+FROM+permissions+WHERE+uid+=+me()");
```

Good luck!

You can read more about running FQL queries [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).
You can read more about the permissions table [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/).
You can read more about the graph api's User object [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Comment: I try to query read_stream permission and got "[read_stream] => 1" is it mean that I already ask for the proper permission.

Comment: Version note: As of 2016 (Graph API v2.5), `limit=0` will now return 0 result, and `read_stream` permission is replaced by `read_posts`

Answer (score 0):

```
$num = 0;
$result = $facebook->api( array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()') );
foreach($result as $photo){
$num++;
}
```

use this, it is the faster to count your friends

Comment: I believe the original poster was trying to do more then just count someones friends.

Comment: FQL is deprecated so don't use fql.