# Facebook apps behaving differently for same code

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

We are using 2 apps for the same purpose but we use on solely for development and the other on pour production server. We are fetching the users friends and their friends likes and interests. 
We see inconsistency in the data fetched. In one app a friend has only likes and no interests while in the other we have both or none.

We are using the facebook php sdk and are querying the graph api with this request

```
$facebook->api('/me?fields=friends.limit(200).offset(0).fields(id,name,likes.limit(100).fields(category),interests.limit(100).fields(category))');
```

Could someone explain why? or how to get consistent data in both apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of your query depends on the Permissions, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions. The Permissions of a user can differ for different appIDs. Do both apps have the same appID?

see also: [Facebook API how to get all wall items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651478/facebook-api-how-to-get-all-wall-items/16651815#16651815)

Comment: Yes, they have same permissions